# scraping text with cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to scrape just `Jung Ho Kang` and `5` from this html and put it into an object. I want to exclude everything in the `(R)` and the `SS`.

```
<td id="lineup-table-top">
  <b class="text-muted pad-left-10">5</b>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jung Ho Kang 
  <small class="text-muted">(R)</small> 
  <small class="text-muted">SS</small>
</td>
```

Here is my code:

```
var someObjArr = [];

$('td#lineup-table-top').each(function(i, element){

    //Get the text from cheerio.
    var text = $(this).text();

    //if undefined, create the object inside of our array.
    if(someObjArr[i] == undefined){

        someObjArr[i] = {};
    };

    //Update the salary property of our object with the text value.
    someObjArr[i].name = text;

    $('b.pad-left-10').each(function(i, element){

        //Get the text from cheerio.
        var text = $(this).text();

        //if undefined, create the object inside of our array.
        if(someObjArr[i] == undefined){

            someObjArr[i] = {};
        };

        //Update the name property of our object with the text value.
        someObjArr[i].batting = text;
    });
});
```

The exact output from the code is as follows:

```
{ batting: '5',
  name: '5   Jung Ho Kang (R) SS 3B' }
{ name: '5   Jung Ho Kang (R) SS' },
```

The Expected output:

```
{ batting: '5',
  name: 'Jung Ho Kang' }
```

I don't know why it appears to be looping twice and I can't figure out how to isolate just the name without it having a class/id associated with it.

Any direction is enthusiastically appreciated.

Comment: In your output you show values that aren't in the HTML you posted. Can you edit your question to include all of the HTML?

Comment: @Jordan Done. My bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you want to scrape only the text nodes in the markup.

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/359

I'm not sure if `nodeType` is supported yet, but you should try to use that first. ([nodeType docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType))

```
$('td#lineup-table-top').contents().each(function(i, element){
    someObjArr[i] = someObjArr[i] || {};

    // The first element in #linup-table-top is batting stats
    if ( i === 0 && $(element).hasClass('pad-left-10') ) {
        someObjArr[i].name = $(element).text().trim();
    }

    // The raw text inside of #lineup-table-top the player name
    if ( element.nodeType === 3 ) {

        someObjArr[i].name = $(element).toString().trim();
    }
});
```

If it's not supported, you can fall back to using `element.type`

```
if ( element.type === 'text' ) {
    someObjArr[i] = someObjArr[i] || {};
    someObjArr[i].name = $(element).toString().trim();
}
```

I used this in the past to scrape only the text within an entire page of markup.

```
// For each DOM element in the page
$('*').each(function(i, element) {
    // Scrape only the text nodes
    $(element).contents().each(function(i, element) {
        if (element.type === 'text') {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Right but I don't want some of the text... I want my output to look like: `{ batting: '5',
  name: 'Jung Ho Kang' }`

Comment: That last edit gets me real close! There are a bunch of strange characters in the string: `{ name: '&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;Jung Ho Kang ' },
,
{ name: ' ' },` <- And it spits out two name attributes one which is empty

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to strip the string. one second

Comment: Try to call `$(element).toString().trim();` lemme know if that works.

Comment: Got it stripped... But I can;t figure out how to get "batting" into the same object..

Comment: Batting should be the first child inside of the markup, so you can do what you were doing before. Lemme edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86728/discussion-between-sails4life-and-cory-danielson).